# How to make the code pause until the user clicks the enter key?

Tags: python, text

I have the following code, and i want the code to pause after each print statement until the user presses the enter key.  How would I go about that?

```
import random

import time

print ("Hello")
print ("What is your name?")
lower_username = str(input("Enter Username: "))
upper_username = lower_username.capitalize()
print ("Hello " + upper_username)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What you ask is not crystal clear, am I right assuming that you want that the answer of the user is on the same line as the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by making all of your `print` statements `input()` statements, they will only continue after a user intervention, e.g. an enter keystroke.

```
import random

import time

print "Hello"
input("What is your name?")
lower_username = str(input("Enter Username: "))
upper_username = lower_username.capitalize()
print "Hello " + upper_username
```

Comment: You've been a little overzealous in your use of `input`, please edit your question to remove the 1st and the last of the invocations — the imports are superflous too.

Comment: i cite the question again... `and i want the code to pause after each print statement until the user presses the enter key` - that is what my code does.

Comment: edited it....but from his question, I'm not sure what he wants either...

Comment: You may be right, I may be wrong, let's see if the OP is going to answer

Comment: Yeah sorry if i was unclear; after each 'print' statement, I want the code to pause until the user clicks enter.  For example, `print ("Hello") #wait until user clicks enter print("What is your name?")

Comment: then you should just turn every `print` statement into an `input()` statement and you will get what you desire ;)

Answer (score 1):

put `input()` at the end of code

Comment: the second edit is just an overcomplication - stay with changing `print` to `input` and all is fine

Comment: it is just extra thing he can do :) why did you downvote?

Comment: because it is not answering the question in a clear way - he needs to put `input()` after every print in order to achieve what he was asking